# prolog family tree locating cousins

Tags: prolog, relationship

[The Cousin Explainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Rp2.png)

Write a program that when given a  person of reference and a degree the program can tell me all of the nth degree cousins that person has. I've started by writing my facts: male/1 female/1 and child/2 these are populated with the names of my family members. I then began writing rules for cousins I figured id write a different rule for every degree so only up to the third cousins. The problems I'm having are as follows.

1. `firstCousin_of(X,Y):-child(X,Z1),child(Y,Z2),child(Z1,Z),child(Z2,Z).` I have this to find a first cousin but the 2nd cousin is more complicated which makes me think there has gotta be a way to do this recursively.
2. I need the rule, `all_cousins(Person, Degree, ListOfCousins)`, which after figuring out all of the nth degree cousins edits a list of all cousins to only include those specific nth degree cousins. I'm used to imperative languages and all i can think about with this is how do I even convey to the rule which people to remove from the list from one rule to another.
3. lastly I have a rule,  `all_cousinsRemoved(Person, Degree, removed(Number, Direction), ListOfCousins)` that I don't even know where to start with but ill need the all_cousins rule for this one because it does the same thing but also only includes cousins in the edited lists w=that were removed nth times either up or down.

Comment: I have a suggestion: since Stackoverflow is really not the best place for such questions, try a mailing list. For example comp.lang.prolog or [swi-prolog.discourse.group](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/). You have very valid questions here it is just not a good fit for this place.

Comment: @TA_intern While one can ask beginner questions at [swi-prolog.discourse.group](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/) they may not get answered as we are not there to teach introductory Prolog. See: [Welcome page](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/welcome-to-discourse/7). IMO the correct choice here is to give a close vote for `Needs more foucus`.

Comment: Ad 1: Is it intended that you admit that everyone is a first cousin of selfsame who has a grand parent?

Comment: @TA_intern: Why shouldn't this question be answered on SO?

Comment: @false yes everyone is a first cousin if they share a grandparent. The other relationships such as the second cousin twice removed get a lot more complicated that's why I don't believe my implementation is the best way.

Comment: @false I don't think it shouldn't be answered. But this is a double negative; in fact, I hope it gets a good answer on Stackoverflow. But it is still not a good fit, since it asks too much, and the answer could be a tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

The best solutions is make a several rules that call other rules, here an example

```
male(dicky).
male(randy).
male(mike).
male(don).
male(elmer).
female(anne).
female(rosie).
female(esther).
female(mildred).
female(greatgramma).
male(blair).
male(god).
female(god).

parent(don,randy).
parent(don,mike).
parent(don,anne).
parent(rosie,randy).
parent(rosie,mike).
parent(rosie,anne).
parent(elmer,don).
parent(mildred,don).
parent(esther,rosie).
parent(esther,dicky).
parent(greatgramma,esther).
parent(randy,blair).

male(mel).
male(teo).
parent(melsr,mel).
parent(melsr,teo).

american(anne).
american(X) :-  ancestor(X,anne).
american(X) :- ancestor(anne,X).
relation(X,Y) :- ancestor(A,X), ancestor(A,Y).

father(X,Y) :- male(X),parent(X,Y).
father(god, _) :- male(god).
mother(X,Y) :- female(X),parent(X,Y).
son(X,Y) :- male(X),parent(Y,X).
daughter(X,Y) :- female(X),parent(Y,X).
grandfather(X,Y) :- male(X),parent(X,Somebody),parent(Somebody,Y).
aunt(X,Y) :- female(X),sister(X,Mom),mother(Mom,Y).
aunt(X,Y) :- female(X),sister(X,Dad),father(Dad,Y).
sister(X,Y) :- female(X),parent(Par,X),parent(Par,Y), X \= Y.
uncle(X,Y) :- brother(X,Par),parent(Par,Y).
cousin(X,Y) :- uncle(Unc , X),father(Unc,Y).
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Somebody),ancestor(Somebody,Y).
brother(X,Y) :-  male(X),parent(Somebody,X),parent(Somebody,Y), X \= Y.
```

[Retrived from this repository](https://github.com/Anniepoo/prolog-examples/blob/master/familytree.pl)

Comment: my questions were more regarding those rules you suggest making. the more complicated ones I stated.

Comment: @GavontiShawnPatton
In prolog, to make life easier, it is necessary to make small rules that solve small problems and these at the same time solve bigger problems by joining them together. The example I showed in the answer is how you can achieve it.

Comment: thats my sugestion

Comment: Thank you I used the child facts to go up from the reference person to the grandparent and back down to the first cousin I then implemented and called a sibling rule to verify that the parents of both the reference child and first cousin were siblings verifying they were cousins. is this something like what you mean?